# CSS Animate SVG stroke stop at last frame

Tags: css, svg

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdXZOx)

In the above codepen there is an SVG that the stroke animates into view, but at the end it just disappears.

Is there a way to keep it into view once its loaded?

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add these two properties to your `.path`

```
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; // Stay on the last frame
    animation-iteration-count: 1;// Run only once
```

Css will be:

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
animation-fill-mode: forwards; // Stay on the last frame
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Codepen is [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNOEKp),its working fine.

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly what the OP asked for, but in case you wish to use svg's `<animate>` tag for your animation and encountered the same issue, you can use the `fill` attribute. Like this:

```
<animate ... fill="freeze"/>
```

This will freeze the animation at its last frame on completion. For example:

```
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 100 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="90" height="10">
    <animate attributeName="width" values="0;90" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill#animate).

Comment: Tried it, because I am thinking of using SMIL animations instead of CSS ones (because even though rather simple, the CSS ones lag like hell). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me out a bunch.